# How can we execute Unit Tests against DOM manipulation?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, qunit

The introduction to QUnit over at [netTuts.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-test-your-javascript-code-with-qunit/) spawns an interesting exchange (never resolved) over how to apply unit tests against actions that manipulate the DOM. The following quote (Alex York) gets to the crux:

> What would be nice is that if you had
>   a function like this:
>
> function add(a, b) { var result = a +
>   b;
>   $(“input#ResultTestBox”).val(result);
>
> In the above test, I would love to
>   test two things: the addition of a and
>   b, and the result correctly being put
>   into a DOM element. I would love to
>   test the second thing by providing
>   some mock HTML. Possible?

But, like I said...unresolved. Resolvable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The latest version of QUnit supports a `#qunit-fixture` element that lets you add HTML to the QUnit web page.

E.g., in your HTML:

```
<ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
<div id="qunit-fixture">test markup, will be hidden</div>
```

and in your JavaScript:

```
$('<input id="ResultTestBox" type="text"/>').appendTo('#qunit-fixture');
var result = add(a, b);

equals(result, $('input#ResultTestBox').val(), "testing result box value");
```

Comment: How is it unit testing when you are actually basing it on real dom manipulations?

Comment: @Tushar that depends on which of the 26 definitions of unit testing you're using.  As long as tests can run independently of each other, they're unit tests according to some definition(s). (such as in the book "Test Driven Development By Example" by Kent Beck)

Answer (score 2):

Surely what you *actually* care about is that the `val` method gets called on the return value of `$(“input#ResultTestBox”)`—you don't need to test the functionality of the jQuery method itself.  Why not inject a mock implementation of the jQuery object and test against that?

Comment: How do you make mock jQuery objects without loosing jQuery itself? Like the idea but having trouble visualizing how you would d mocks in code.

Comment: @Sukima, you would refactor your original code so that the `$` object is passed in as a parameter, and by default make that parameter value jQuery.  Then in your unit tests you pass in your mock object

Comment: Mocking (at least for things other than remote calls, database queries...) is a code smell.  If you can test the result of the call rather than obverve the fact that the call itself happened, that is usually much better.

Comment: @herman if my code depends on a service implementation why wouldn't I mock the service?  If I change the service behaviour then I shouldn't have to change the unit tests for every dependency to reflect the change.  If I _break_ the service behaviour then the unit tests for every dependency shouldn't also break.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex if you refactor the code in a way that changes the interface of the service (for example you put some more things in the service that were previously repeated in each client) but without changing the overall behaviour, then you should be able to verify that your refactoring didn't break anything, by running the tests without having to change them all first.  In other words, avoiding the mocking means avoiding the tight coupling between tests and implementation code.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex In this particular case, he may want to replace the use of jQuery in his production code with plain old javascript, and use the existing tests to ensure the behaviour hasn't changed.  With your solution, the test would break even if the code is fine.

Comment: @herman interesting idea. I would say that in your example he should unit test his plain-JS implementation of `$` to confirm that it behaves as jQuery did.  For me, what you are describing is an integration test - not a unit test

Comment: @SteveGreatrex 1) With the example, I didn't mean that he would replace $ with his own implementation.  I meant that he would replace the code to update the value with something like `document.querySelector('selector').value = ...` instead of using jQuery.  Now with your solution suddenly the test needs to mock a `document` instead of `$`.  2) even if he would make an abstraction of this and inject a dependency which uses jQuery or plain JS, then when he wants to test the plain JS version, he still has his original problem.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex 3) Whether this is a unit test or not depends on which of the 26 definitions of "unit test" you use.  I only call a test an integration test if different systems get called (HTTP REST services, database, ...).  But that's just terminology, doesn't change the usefulness (or lack thereof) of the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them in [env.js](https://github.com/envjs/env-js), if you don't want the hassle of creating html page sandboxes for all your tests.